# Using MongoTemplate with MongoClient and UserCredentials

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

One of the application uses MongoClient as core for interacting with MongoDB in which authentication has been enabled recently. In this mongoClient is initialize as:

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddress, Arrays.asList(MongoCredential.createCredential(userName, dbName, password.toCharArray())));
```

However at many places app uses mongoTemplate to query the data. Now if MongoTemplate is created as :

```
new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, dbName);
```

It leads to authentication failure.

The only way seems to pass user credentials to MongoTemplate is via using UserCredentials class by

However if we pass UserCredentials as :

```
    public MongoTemplate(Mongo mongo, String databaseName, UserCredentials userCredentials) {
```

Which results to :

```
Usage of 'UserCredentials' with 'MongoClient' is no longer supported. Please use 'MongoCredential' for 'MongoClient' or just 'Mongo'.
```

It seems like two different API exists in parallel. What's the best way so that both of them can live together.

This app uses mongodata version as '1.10.6.RELEASE'

Comment: I don't see "two different API" in your question. What are the 2 APIs?

Comment: I mean to say inability to use UserCredentials with MongoClient where none of them seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential("user", "database","password".toCharArray());
ServerAddress address = new ServerAddress("mymongo.mycompany.com", 62797);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(address, Arrays.asList(mongoCredential));
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, "database");
```

Comment: In this case getting org.springframework.dao.PermissionDeniedDataAccessException: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:23423" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." , "code" : 18 , "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed"}; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1: 23423" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." , "code" : 18 , "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed"}

Comment: @tarunkumar There are various overloaded versions of `createXXCrendential`. The default one I used tries to detect the best mechanism, but it may not always work. Try the other ones, especially `createMongoCRCredential`. Help yourself by debugging: If I were you, I'd write a simple Java client and try to connect to the Mongo instance; your problem isn't deprecation warning or `MongoTemplate` configuration anymore, and without knowing the details about your server, I can't provide step-by-step instructions to you.

Comment: MongoClient(address, Arrays.asList(mongoCredential)) constructor is deprecated

Comment: @rohanagarwal It's been 15 months since I'd posted this answer, a lot of water has flown under the bridge. If you've an alternative suggestion, feel free to put in comment.

Comment: As per the docs - prefer MongoClient(ServerAddress, MongoCredential, MongoClientOptions). One can construct a MongoClientOptions using MongoClientOptions.builder().build() which was earlier done by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials("YOUR_USER_NAME", "YOUR_PASSWORD");
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new Mongo(), "YOUR_DATABASE", userCredentials);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

And to create database repositories just use `MongoRepository` like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User,Serializable>{
    User findById(String id);
}
```

Comment: I think `MongoDbFactory` may be deprecated.

Comment: i have referenced it from their docs . link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-db-factory-java

Comment: I know; doesn't mean it's not deprecated. The best way to know is to run this code with deprecation warning enabled. I will leave that to the OP.

Comment: Ok . if it is depricated i will definitely update my answer

Comment: @ark0n . Use MongoClient bean for authentication . ex: `return new MongoClient(singletonList(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017)),
      singletonList(MongoCredential.createCredential("name", "db", "pwd".toCharArray())));`

Answer (score 0):

In this case seems like it was problem of applying user authentication at mongod server end.

Needed authentication was applied to mongo and has been validated by

```
db.auth('user','pass');
```

command which results to 1. However database at that time doesn't exists. Afterwards database was created first by inserted a dummy record and permissions were assigned.

App uses all together a different DB for unit test cases for which it looks like configuration was not correctly applied where this issue was arriving.

Once corrected applied

```
 new MongoClient(serverAddress, Arrays.asList(MongoCredential.createCredential(userName, dbName, password.toCharArray())));
```

seems to work fine. However at same time mongo driver errors are a bit cryptic without much explanation leading to making debugging time consuming.